# terraform should forward two rules to one sqs-que

Tags: terraform, terraform-provider-aws, aws-event-bridge

I do not understand how I can tell terraform that it should create two rules for an aws-eventbridge which should send an event to the same sqs-queue if a rule is triggered. Example below. It is working in aws if i configure it over the aws-management console

```
  source  = "terraform-aws-modules/eventbridge/aws"
  version = "1.14.0"

  bus_name = "staging"

  rules = {
    update = {
      description = "Event_To_SQS_Staging"
      enabled     = true
      event_pattern = jsonencode({
        source = [
          "service"
        ]
        detail = {
          email = [{
            prefix = "testeventbridge"
          }]
        }
      })
    },

    delete = {
      description = "Delete_Event_To_SQS_Staging"
      enabled     = true
      event_pattern = jsonencode({
        source = [
          "service"
        ],
        detail-type = [
          "DeleteEvent"
        ]
      })
    }
  }

  targets = {
    update = [
      {
        name = aws_sqs_queue.event_queue_staging.name
        arn  = aws_sqs_queue.event_queue_staging.arn

      }
    ],
    delete = [
      {
        name = aws_sqs_queue.event_queue_staging.name
        arn  = aws_sqs_queue.event_queue_staging.arn
      }
    ]

  }
}
```

the error i see is

```
Two different items produced the key "EventQueue" in this
│ 'for' expression. If duplicates are expected, use the ellipsis (...) after
│ the value expression to enable grouping by key.
```

Comment: The error comes from `'for' expression`, yet you haven't shown any TF code with `for`. Please provide full code that produces the error.

Comment: Since i am not a terraform expert my assumption is that the for is coming from this https://registry.terraform.io/modules/terraform-aws-modules/eventbridge/aws/latest#input_targets terraform-module. so i believe i can not show you the the `for`:-(.